# How can I add "boxes" (just bordered rectangles) to a JLayeredPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, jpanel, jlayeredpane

My overall goal is to create a jigsaw puzzle game that moves a set of images around the GUI screen with mousedrag. My current issue is to make this snapping function that when the mouse dragging the image releases, the image will snap into a predetermined place. This is where I want to create "boxes". I want to create 16 boxes for the 16 puzzle pieces and use their coordinates as the snapping location for the images when I release the mouse. (Just how in puzzle games the pieces snap to the correct place when you hover a general area). I am attempting this by making 16 JPanels, but I don't know if this is the smart way. Also, it seems I can't even add the JPanels to my JLayeredPane. I tried to set a border for one of the JPanels to help me see if it was added, and it was not.

Mouse drag works fine, everything works fine. I just want to be able to add some sort of representation of a box that the images when released by the mouse will snap into the box's location. Please let me know if you have any insights to this problem!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class Gui1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Gui1();
    }

    public Gui1() {    //Constructor for setting up the GUI
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            JPanel canvas1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas2 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas3 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas4 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas5 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas6 = new JPanel();         
            JPanel canvas7 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas8 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas9 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas10 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas11 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas12 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas13 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas14 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas15 = new JPanel();
            JPanel canvas16 = new JPanel();
            canvas1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
                 canvas1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue,10));      
            pane.add(canvas1, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new ImageGrab());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could use Box2D since you want to use pseudo-collision. [See here](http://box2d.org/)

Comment: I would suggest making a virtual grid, probably using java.awt.Rectangle to define the boundaries. You could the calculate collisions/overlaps of the piece/component (via its getBounds method) with the virtual grid

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried a lot of ways to use some sort of grid, panel, rectangle what not, but nothing seems to be adding to to GUI. What layer do I have to add the rectangle to so that it sticks? I get this error when I try to add it to the JFrame http://gyazo.com/19700aece5cf1e5e58ce94ca22daa22d

Comment: and how can i give the rectangle a border so that I know it is on the GUI? I can't seem to find any border methods.

Comment: Rectangle can be painted by using Graphics#draw(Shape)